# Is loading client side code on demand possible in latest version (0.9.x) of meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am looking at using Meteor to build a real-time data application, since Meteor does so much real-time updating and other related stuff itself. The only thing that is stopping me is that Meteor downloads everything file (except files on the public and server folders) on to client. Let's say, I am developing a very large application containing so many modules. Only certain modules will be available for certain users. So all code related to other modules will download unnecessarily. The initial page load is also going to take a long time.  May be there will be some security issues as well.

I tried using IRLibloader plugin to load the JS files by placing them in public folder. So is there a way to configure Meteor in such a way that, it downloads only the code that is required and later download the code for other modules when necessary? If it is not possible, then can you please guide me to other good practices using Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. A complete solution is the `anti:modules` package. First add it to the app:

```
meteor add anti:modules
```

Then create `/layers` folder inside your project and place your optional files in its subfolder:

```
/
  layers
    fancyModule
      someFile.module.js
      anotherFile.module.js
      ...
```

Then in your code create a global module:

```
theApp = Module('$global').as('myApp');
```

and load it when necessary:

```
theApp.require('fancyModule', function () {
  console.log('fancyModule code loaded');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That is an awesome package. Looks like you are one of the contributors to it. Is there any target in your roadmap to support css files?

Comment: Is it possible to define templates in `*.module.html` files? I have defined a template in my `example.module.html`. In `Router.map`, I am using WaitOn method to load the example module while navigating to "/example" route. But I am getting this 'Couldn't find a template named "example"' error. Please help.